# Insertar vinculos en imagenes e insertar en html

Tags: html, img, enlace

Hay manera de insertar hipervinctulos en imagenes para despues colocarlos como elementos `<img>`

Problema:
Tengo una imagen en la cual se han implementado los botones directamente en ella. Obviamente es muy cumplicado hacer detección del boton a menos de que todo se maneje con `position absolute` y poner una rejilla sobre el boton.

Hay alguna manera de que en la imagen se pueden insertar hipervinculos para cuando se incluya en `html` detecte esos enlaces en su posición.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen de ejemplo, puede verse que el boton es directamente insertado en ella, es un ejemplo simple, pero hay imagenes que tienen muchos botones y necesito detectar estos botones de la mejor manera.

¿Hay forma de trabajar con `hipervinculos` directamente en la imagen al incluir en `html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con los elementos `<map>` y `<area>` y el atributo `usemap` del elemento `<img>`.

Aquí hay un ejemplo que crea dos "botones" invisibles, uno si pulsas al lado izquierdo de la imagen, y otro si pulsas en el el lado derecho de la imagen.

```html
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/es/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" usemap="#botones">
    
<map name="botones">
    <area shape="rect" coords="50,50,158,266" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alert('Lado izquierdo');">
    <area shape="rect" coords="159,50,266,266" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alert('Lado derecho');">
</map>
```

Primero defines la imagen con un atributo `usemap` en el que indicas las áreas clickables de la imagen.

Después defines un elemento `map` y varias areas clickables en las que indicas las coordenadas y el tipo de área (`rect` son rectángulos, pero podrían ser también elipses o círculos e incluso polígonos más complejos). Generalmente esto funciona como un enlace en la que defines el href y al hacer clic te redirige a la página que sea; pero puedes evitar ese comportamiento poniendo `javascript:void(0)`; en el atributo `href` y definiendo un listener personalizado para el evento `onclick`.

Si tienes varias imágenes donde los botones están siempre en la misma posición puedes reutilizar tus mapas de área. Si están en diferentes posiciones, tendrás que hacer mapas diferentes.

Más info: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Comment: Interesante, como puedo establecer un color de area? para ver en que posición se encuentra y empezar a mover coordenadas, ya intente poner class y style, pero no se muestra el color de area.

Comment: Los atributos `class` y `style` no están permitidos en el elemento `area` ya que un área es algo invisible, y como tal no se puede decorar. Para hacer dibujos con formas, colores, etc se podría usar un `<canvas>`.